# React login advice wanted

Tags: mysql, reactjs, react-native, mysql-workbench

So i am making a react project currently, and i have established connection to a MYSQL database with encryption. But i have no idea of how to make it possible to login afterwards.

```js
app.post("/signup", (req, res) => {
    const { email, firstname, lastname, password } = req.body;
    const hashedPassword = encrypt(password);

    db.query("INSERT INTO accounts (email, fName, lName, password, iv) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [
        email,
        firstname,
        lastname,
        hashedPassword.password,
        hashedPassword.iv 
    ], (err, result)=>{
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Success!");
        }
    }
    );
    
});
```

This is where i store data inside the database.

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks like you want to register a new user, since you insert new values inside your database. For a login, you'd just have to check whether the user info needed for the login is correct and exists in your database.

But either way, you should have some input fields where the user can login or register. After the user clicked the submit button you can execute a function which runs the sql query. After the query result was successful, you can proceed and show another view (a dashboard or whatever your app is about).